# Bootstrap 3.0 breaking JWPlayer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jwplayer6

I have two fiddles, both are the exact same code with one exception: in the second I included bootstrap 3.0 (bootstrap.min.css), nothing changed in the code. Both are like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="mediaplayer250"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer250").setup({
   file: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_flash.mp4",
   autostart: true,
   tracks:[{
      file: "//thumbs.thehun.net/video/2014-04/250533d24fe409be_proverb.vtt",
      kind: "thumbnails"
   }]
});
```

Note that playing the video and moving the mouse over the progress bar shows a thumbnail preview neatly located inside the reserved area

In the second version the thumbnail appears larger than the area it should fit in. How can I fix this? And is this a problem in Bootstrap 3.0 or in JWplayer?

[the first jsfiddle, showing the correct tooltips](http://jsfiddle.net/P9eJK/)

[the second link, this one shows an sizing problem in the tooltips](http://jsfiddle.net/P9eJK/1/)

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Comment: The answer JWPlayer provided me with: don't use Bootstrap 3... very disappointing...

Comment: I'm a little late but there is clearly a better solution than not using bootstrap and I guess the people who answered you have just a little idea about their own product - at least regarding it's CSS :p Check my answer and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the following bootstrap rule:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now to fix the problem with jwlayer without changing this rule for all bootstrap/site elements (which could cause unwanted behaviour) add this CSS rule to your custom CSS:

```
.jwplayer *, .jwplayer *:before, .jwplayer *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box!important;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box!important;
  box-sizing: content-box!important;
}
```

See your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P9eJK/5/ 
And sorry for the late answer...